# Assigning Entity Framework Code First Navigation Properties on Create

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, navigation-properties

Suppose we have these two classes:

```
public class Parent
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ParentID { get; set; }
    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

Suppose I create one of each with the following methods:

```
//Create a parent with new children
public void CreateParent(MyDbContext context)
{
    context.Parents.Add(new Parent
    { 
         Children = new List<Child>() 
         { 
              new Child(),
              new Child(),
              new Child()                
         }
    });

    context.SaveChanges();
}

//Create a child with a new parent
public void CreateChild(MyDbContext context)
{
    context.Children.Add(new Child
    { 
         Parent = new Parent()
    });

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Will either of these methods create both Parent and Child objects with foreign keys appropriately assigned? My gut tells me that CreateParent would work, but CreateChild would not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, both of these methods will create the Parent and Child records as well with the ParentID foreign key set. If you run e.g. the first one, the result you will get will be the following:

[image]

And as another answer states you don't need the ParentID however Entity Framework will recognize it as the Foreign Key used for the Parent association and you don't have to use the virtual keyword neither at the Children nor at the Parent property to make your code work, however if you wan't Lazy Loading to work with these properties you will need them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes both functions work correctly, adding both Parent and Child records with the correct association between them.

Running CreateParent will yield one new Parent record and three Child records associated with it (through ParentID).

Running CreateChild will create one new Child and one new Parent record, associated correctly.

Comment: I see you corrected the function names and I'm glad it works correctly, hope my answer helped :)

Comment: Honestly, I ended up just writing a test project and checking myself. My problem had nothing to do with EF function names - that wasn't code that came from a project, and intellisense would never let me make such errors. The function names weren't the purpose of the question. While it may have been worth fixing for others to see, the corrections would have been better suggested as comments. If you change your answer to focus on the actual question that was asked, I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: That's true, I've fixated too much on the syntax error not the original question, but I changed my answer to focus more on the foreign key creation :)